# How to add parent node of each json object in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm newbie to JSON parsing and lots of way but here just giving my expected output.If you can help or can ignore this.

I took a model with the following property.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="add-field")]
   public string addfield { get; set; }="{";
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   public string indexed { get; set; }
   public string stored { get; set; }
```

Then after serialize model object I have got the folllowing json object

```
{add-field": "{",
    "name": "ID",
    "type": "string",
    "indexed": "true",
    "stored": "true"
  },` {
    "add-field": "{",
    "name": "Address",
    "type": "string",
    "indexed": "true",
    "stored": "true"
  }
}
```

But I want it into the following format for api format:

```
{"add-field":{
     "name":"ID",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },
     "add-field":{
     "name":"I",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },

 "add-field":{
     "name":"Address",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true }
}
```

How I can do this?Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "add-field" should be a type not a string. [JSON Basics: What You Need to Know](http://www.elated.com/articles/json-basics/)

Comment: what type should be ? You mean List or array ?@Plutonix

Comment: No, type == class.  Are you *sure* there isnt also some square brackets around some part of it?  defining `add-field` as a string and assigning "{" to it doesnt do what you think.  `"{"` is not the same as `{`.

Comment: Yes after serialization there was square brackets and I have remove that because I need the following format to call api.{"add-field":{
     "name":"ID",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },
     "add-field":{
     "name":"I",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },

 "add-field":{
     "name":"Address",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true }
}

Comment: I meant if there was *supposed* to be square brackets in the json for the API.  Note that the json you show as how you need it/want it, is *not* valid json because of the duplicated "add-field" keys.

Comment: Thanks @ Plutonix works your idea. I've resolved that issue in the following way.                        
 public class Student
        {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "add-field")]
        public StudentDetails addfield { get; set; }
        }   public class  StudentDetails 
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string indexed { get; set; }
            public string stored { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for **J**ava **S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, which means that a JSON is composed by *Objects*.

In JS objects can be defined as

```
object:{
    field1:value1,
    field2:value2,
}
```

Kind of like the C# object initialization

```
new Object{
    Field1 = value1,
    Field2 = value2,
};
```

Notice that in both the **root is an object**, since whatever is inside the brackets are properties. So if you want

```
"add-field":{
    "name":"ID",
    "type":"string",
    "stored":true 
}
```

you need something like this:

```
public class Add-Field {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string type { get; set; }
     public string indexed { get; set; }
     public string stored { get; set; }
}
```

**WATCHOUT**

The JSON you presented:

```
{"add-field":{
     "name":"ID",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },
     "add-field":{
     "name":"I",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true },

 "add-field":{
     "name":"Address",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true }
}
```

Won't work, the right way to do it would be using arrays, like this:

```
{
    "add-fields":[
    {
        "name":"ID",
        "type":"string",
        "stored":true },
    {
        "name":"I",
        "type":"string",
        "stored":true },
    {
         "name":"Address",
         "type":"string",
         "stored":true }
    ]
}
```

Or

```
[
   {
       "name":"ID",
       "type":"string",
       "stored":true },
   {
       "name":"I",
       "type":"string",
       "stored":true },
   {
       "name":"Address",
       "type":"string",
       "stored":true }
]
```

Which would require  `public List<Add-Field> add-fields {get;set;}`

Comment: Thanks @J.Pichardo. I'll try and let u know.